# Python multiprocessing issue with passing multiple variables / global variables into function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables, map-function

When I run the code below, the global variable 'ticker' is not defined in the compile() function.

Goal: How do I pass multiple variables into the multiprocessing pool.map() function to make this code work?

The code at the bottom of the post works for a single ticker, but I have issues turning it into a for loop.

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

global ticker
global lst

lst = ['BABA','MSFT','NVDA']

def compile(file_list):
    print(file_list)
    print(f'C: {ticker}')

def main():
    print(f'B: {ticker}')
    file_list = [1,2,3]
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2) as pool:
        results_df = pool.map(compile, file_list)
    print(f'D: {ticker}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for ticker in lst:
        print(f'A: {ticker}')
        main()
```

Output:

```
A: BABA
B: BABA
1
2
3

multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/Users/xxx/Desktop/OptionsData/example 2.py", line 12, in compile
    print(f'C: {ticker}')
NameError: name 'ticker' is not defined
```

I have tried placing the for loop before the if **name**=='**main**' statement, and while the output is different, it is still not correct (am I placing the for loop in the correct spot?).

I have tried passing multiple arguments to the pool.map multiprocessing function `results_df = pool.map(compile, file_list, ticker)` but it says 'not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

The following code works on a single ticker, I want to turn it into a for loop to run on multiple tickers and have been having trouble getting it to work:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def compile(file_list):
    print(file_list)
    print(f'C: {ticker}')

def main():
    print(f'B: {ticker}')
    file_list = [1,2,3]
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2) as pool:
        results_df = pool.map(compile, file_list)
    print(f'D: {ticker}')

global ticker
ticker ='BABA'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'A: {ticker}')
    main()
```

Output:

```
A: BABA
B: BABA
1
C: BABA
2
C: BABA
3
C: BABA
D: BABA
[Finished in 347ms]
```

Comment: `global` has no meaning outside functions.

Comment: `global ticker` and `global lst` aren't in the right place. You're only supposed to use the `global` keyword within a function. But I also think you need to look up to see if globals even work at all in a multiprocessing setting.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You want 3 processes that all process the same ticker with a different element of `file_list`? Then do the same thing with the other ticker symbols?

Comment: Or do you want to use `file_list` and `lst` in parallel?

Comment: I added code at the bottom showing that the global format works for a single ticker but when it runs as a for loop there is an issue.

Comment: You are asking two questions in one and it has two topics; using global variables and passing arguments to a thread pool. Please consider only asking the question regarding the thread pool, as the question related to the global variables has answers in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use `starmap` to handle multiple arguments.  In the code below `zip` pairs up each "file" with the same ticker in each loop iteration to generate the argument list for each `compile`, e.g.:

```py
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> list(zip([1, 2, 3], repeat('MSFT')))
[(1, 'MSFT'), (2, 'MSFT'), (3, 'MSFT')]
```

Global variables don't work with multiprocessing.  Processes don't share their global namespace so changes in the main process don't reflect in the child processes, so the ticker must be passed to the child processes.

Also, no reason to create the pool more than once.

Solution:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from itertools import repeat

def compile(file, ticker):
    print(f'C: {file} {ticker}')

def main():
    lst = ['BABA', 'MSFT', 'NVDA']
    with Pool(cpu_count() - 2) as pool:
        for ticker in lst:
            print(f'A: {ticker}')
            file_list = [1, 2, 3]
            results_df = pool.starmap(compile, zip(file_list, repeat(ticker)))
            print(f'D: {ticker}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
A: BABA
C: 1 BABA
C: 2 BABA
C: 3 BABA
D: BABA
A: MSFT
C: 1 MSFT
C: 2 MSFT
C: 3 MSFT
D: MSFT
A: NVDA
C: 1 NVDA
C: 2 NVDA
C: 3 NVDA
D: NVDA
```

In fact, you can process all combinations of files and tickers with `itertools.product` in one `starmap` call:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from itertools import product

def compile(file, ticker):
    print(f'{file} {ticker}')

def main():
    with Pool() as pool:
        tickers = ['BABA', 'MSFT', 'NVDA']
        file_list = [1, 2, 3]
        results_df = pool.starmap(compile, product(file_list, tickers))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
1 BABA
1 MSFT
2 BABA
1 NVDA
2 NVDA
3 BABA
3 MSFT
3 NVDA
2 MSFT
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can always pass `ticker` as an explicit argument to your pool worker function, `compile`. But if you instead want to initialize a global variable so that it is available in *all the pool processes*, then use a *pool initializer*:

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def init_pool_processes(t):
    global ticker

    ticker = t

def compile(file): #  A list is not being passed
    print(file)
    print(f'C: {ticker}')

def main():
    print(f'B: {ticker}')
    file_list = [1,2,3]
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(ticker,)) as pool:
        results_df = pool.map(compile, file_list)
    print(f'D: {ticker}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = ['BABA','MSFT','NVDA']
    for ticker in lst:
        print(f'A: {ticker}')
        main()
```